# Processing - Loops - amount of circles decrease

Tags: for-loop, processing, nested-loops

Here is a grid of crosses in circles currently 5x5. I'm attempting to get a row of 5, followed by a row of 4 underneath, then 3, then 2 etc. I've tried changing the for loops and the values but nothing is working. Do I need to use rows and columns?

```
int x=20;
int y=30;
size(100,100); //set size of canvas screen

for(int i=0; i<5 ; i++) 
{
for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
{
x=x+10; //add 10 to value stored in variable x


ellipse(x,y,10,10);
line (x-5,y,x+5,y);
line (x,y-5,x,y+5);
}
x=20;
y=y+10;

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please review [ask] a question and post a [mcve].  What does "Do I need to use rows and columns" mean?  What language is this in (java, C#, javascript)?  What isn't working?  Is an exception being thrown?  What have you done to try and debug it?

Comment: @Gaber-ber I agree with most of what you're saying, but notice the [tag:processing] tag. Processing is a language.

Comment: My mistake about the language.  Thank you for drawing my attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in your last post, the best thing you can do is to get out a piece of graph paper and a pencil and draw out a few examples. Do this until you find a pattern, and you can use that in your `for` loops. Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on `for` loops in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/for-loops).

Another thing you might try is separating each row into its own `for` loop. Don't worry about nested `for` loops right now; just get it working with 5 individual `for` loops, one for each row. When you have that working, you'll be able to look for patterns that you can use to condense the whole thing into one nested `for` loop.

One more thing you might do is separate drawing a row of circles into its own function, which might be defined like this:

```
void drawRow(float circleY, int circleCount){
```

Then you'd put your inner `for` loop inside this function. Now that you have this, you can write another `for` loop that calls this function.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your tutorial was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to reduce the number of circles drawn in the OUTER FOR LOOP. Compare with something I did :)

```
size(500, 500);

background(255);
 
int gridSize = 15;

int nTimes = gridSize;

int num = 1; //number the circles

float circleD = (width/gridSize);

float w = (width/gridSize)/2;

float h = (height/gridSize)/2;

float hOffset = h;

float wOffset = w;

int count = 1;
 
for(int i = 0; i < nTimes; i++){
  for(int j = 1; j <= gridSize; j++){ //horizontal
    if(count %2 == 1){
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    }
    else{
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    ellipse(wOffset, hOffset, circleD, circleD);
    fill(14);
    textSize(circleD/6);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    text(num, wOffset, hOffset);
    num++;
    wOffset += circleD;
   
  }
  gridSize -= 1;
  wOffset = w;
  hOffset += circleD;
  count += 1;
}
```